# Error when using if_else applied to times and dates

Tags: r, if-statement

Below's a sample of my dataset, where I have GPS positions (`Latitude` and `Longitude`) and the date and time they were registered:

```
> head(datanet)
   Date & Time [Local]  Latitude Longitude
1:    18/06/2018 03:01 -2.434901  34.85359
2:    18/06/2018 03:06 -2.434598  34.85387
3:    18/06/2018 03:08 -2.434726  34.85382
4:    18/06/2018 03:12 -2.434816  34.85371
5:    18/06/2018 03:16 -2.434613  34.85372
6:    18/06/2018 03:20 -2.434511  34.85376
```

I would like to create a column `split` which will look at each row and will show `Night` if the time in the first column is in the interval [18h00:06h00] and `Day` if the time in the first column is [06h00:18h00]. Here how I've been approaching this although bear in mind I'm a beginner:

```
> datanet[, DateTime := dmy_hm(`Date & Time [Local]`)]
> head(datanet)
   Date & Time [Local]  Latitude Longitude            DateTime
1:    18/06/2018 03:01 -2.434901  34.85359 2018-06-18 03:01:00
2:    18/06/2018 03:06 -2.434598  34.85387 2018-06-18 03:06:00
3:    18/06/2018 03:08 -2.434726  34.85382 2018-06-18 03:08:00
4:    18/06/2018 03:12 -2.434816  34.85371 2018-06-18 03:12:00
5:    18/06/2018 03:16 -2.434613  34.85372 2018-06-18 03:16:00
6:    18/06/2018 03:20 -2.434511  34.85376 2018-06-18 03:20:00
> datanet$split<-if_else((hour(DateTime) >= 6) &
+                          (hour(DateTime) < 18), "Day", "Night")
Error in hour(DateTime) : object 'DateTime' not found
```

Am I on the right track and how can I fix this error?

Any input is appreciated

Comment: Shouldn't it be `datanet$DateTime` or use `with(datanet, if_else((hour(DateTime), ..`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'DateTime' column is within in the `datanet` dataset, so we need either `$`

```
datanet$split<- if_else((hour(datane$DateTime) >= 6) &
                      (hour(datanet$DateTime) < 18), "Day", "Night")
```

---

Or use `with`

```
datanet$split <- with(datenet, if_else((hour(DateTime) >= 6) &
                     (hour(DateTime) < 18), "Day", "Night"))
```

---

Also, considering that the original data is `data.table`, syntax would be

```
library(data.table)
datanet[, split := if_else((hour(DateTime) >= 6) &
                     (hour(DateTime) < 18), "Day", "Night")]
```

Or without using any `if_else`

```
datanet[, split := c("Night", "Day")[1 + ((hour(DateTime) >= 6) &
                      (hour(DateTime) < 18))]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that your `Local` column is text, you should be able to just compare against time literals:

```
datanet$split <- ifelse(datanet$Local >= '18:00' | datanet$Local <= '06:00',
    'Night', 'Day')
```